# find occurences of a class and if there is only one then hide with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dynamic

I'm trying to hide a button depending on how many occurrences of a certain class there are.

I am dynamically putting data into a page and for each dynamic div i put in i assign it the class "propdata" I need to count how many occurrences there are of "propdata" and if there is only one occurrence i need to hide the button with a class of "topbook"

Hope that makes sense?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property like this:

```
// get total elements with class propdata
var cnt = $('.propdata').length;

// is there only one element with class propdata
if (cnt === 1){
  // hide the element with class topbook
  $('.topbook').hide();
}
```

Or you can make it shorter like this:

```
if ($('.propdata').length === 1){
  $('.topbook').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.propdata').length == 1)
    $('.topbook').hide();
```